# AWS-CLI : to download IAM user with policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

aws : A single command(aws-cli) to get the IAM user name with the what all permission he/she have , would be great if can be downloaded as an excel or csv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below command to get all the policy attached to an iam user. (You must be having permissions to list-users and list-user-policies before using the below commands)

```
aws iam list-attached-user-policies --user-name username | jq -r '.AttachedPolicies[].PolicyArn' | awk -F'policy/' {'print $NF'}
```

(Make sure to replace `username` with some actual iam username in the above command)

If you want to get the list of all users and user-policies attached to those users, you can use the below one line command. The below command will get all the `iam users` and then will find the `user-policies` attached to that user and will put in a CSV file. The first column will contain `username` and second column will contain `policies separated by spaces.

```
for u_name in $(aws iam list-users | jq -r '.Users[].UserName') ; do permissions="$(aws iam list-attached-user-policies --user-name ${u_name} | jq -r '.AttachedPolicies[].PolicyArn' | awk -F'policy/' {'print $NF'} | tr '\n' ' ')" ; echo "${u_name}, ${permissions}" >> iam_users.csv ; done
```

Comment: You saved my day ! cheers !

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the results for a single user then you want [list-attached-user-policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-attached-user-policies.html).  However, this will result in the value being returned as json.  To get it into a csv style format check out the guide on how to [control the CLI output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html).  You should be able to get the output into a delimited format for programmatic parsing.  I do not believe you'll be able to generate an .xlsx file directly from the AWS CLI.

Comment: Yes, generating an excel file directly from aws-cli won't be possible. He need to use different parsing program for formatting.